# How to avoid duplicate inserts for an OrientDB database?

Tags: sql, orientdb, on-duplicate-key

In SQL there's a query `INSERT IGNORE` which keeps duplicate entries out of the database based on the primary key. But is there a way to achieve this functionality in OrientDB since the primary key concept here is kind of achieved using the `@rid` concept?

Comment: Unrelated, but: "*in SQL there's a query Insert ignore*" - no there isn't. SQL (the query language) does not define such a thing. One specific DBMS implements an extension to the SQL language supporting that.

Comment: So should it be changed to MySQL (I guess MySQL supports that `INSERT IGNORE` thing)? Or is it okay to keep the question this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a unique index on that class, so you can avoid duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [UPSERT](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html)?

```
UPDATE Profile SET nick = 'Luca' UPSERT WHERE nick = 'Luca'
```

Please create an index against "nick" property.